# Android - Spinners

Tags: android, arrays

I have a question and know this has been asked a million times, I am fairly new to Android Programming. So I am kinda boggled.

I have created two parallel arrays - containing phrases in two languages.As the spinner changes it value(from 1st array) - the textview should be updated to reflect the translated phrase (in the second array).

The two arrays are created in string.xml, similar to below and the spinner gets it value from there.

```
<string-array name="array_name">
    <item>phrase1</item>
    <item>phrase2</item>
    <item>phrase3</item>
    <item>phrase4</item>
</string-array>
```

Im not sure how to go about doing this or if this is a viable way of doing it.... but boggled I remain....

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set OnItemSelectedListener to spinner and change the text

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   textView.setText(getResources().getTextArray(R.array.array_name)[position]);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {    
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you kozaxinan,it worked like a bomb.I appreciate the help.